# Segment Fualt when I pass a ptr to a function after I malloc a memory, but if I didn't malloc, it was fun?

Tags: c

this is a double circue link. dev_num, blk_num and status are not issued about my question.

```
   typedef struct buf_node {
    unsigned            dev_num;
    unsigned            blk_num;
    unsigned            status:2;
    struct buf_node     *ptr_prev_free_q;
    struct buf_node     *ptr_next_free_q;
    } stc_buf_header;
```

this is a buffer node which contented a identity buf_header and a data field

```
 typedef struct {
    stc_buf_header      *buf_header;
    stc_mm              *data_area;
    } stc_buffer;
```

this is the double circue link which holds the free buffer node waiting for use(like UNIX)

```
typedef struct free_lk_node {
    stc_buffer          *lk_header;
    unsigned            len;
} stc_free_lk;
```

AND, now I define a function to init the double circue link

```
int init(stc_buffer *lk_header, unsigned dev_num, unsigned blk_num){

printf("buf_header\t%p\n", lk_header->buf_header);
printf("lk_header\t%p\n", lk_header);

printf("dev_num\t%d\n", lk_header->buf_header->dev_num);
printf("blk_num\t%d\n", lk_header->buf_header->blk_num);

lk_header->buf_header->dev_num = dev_num;
lk_header->buf_header->blk_num = blk_num;
lk_header->buf_header->status = 0x0;
lk_header->buf_header->ptr_next_free_q = lk_header->buf_header;
lk_header->buf_header->ptr_prev_free_q = lk_header->buf_header;
lk_header->data_area->data = -1; // means that this node is header of the          link
}
```

the printf() statement was used to debug when I got this bug.

OK, now,if I write like this in main()

```
int main(){
    stc_free_lk *link = (stc_free_lk*)malloc(sizeof(stc_free_lk));
    init(link->lk_header, (unsigned)0, (unsigned)0);

    return 0;
}
```

when it runs to the point at printf() statement, there will raise a Segment Fualt error

However, if I write like this in main()

```
int main(){
    stc_free_lk link;
    init(link.lk_header, (unsigned)0, (unsigned)0);

    return 0;
}
```

EVERYTHING IS OK. WHY??, it makes me confoused...(-o-)#

Comment: it's actually *not* OK even in the second instance, it only SEEMS okay because of the stack. Try compiling the second instance with -O2 and see if it crashes (probably will).

Answer (score 3):

First of all, use `%p` for printing addresses, not `%d`.

And your problem is that `malloc` just allocates memory, it **does not initialize it**. And you `malloc` call only initialized the memory for a `struct stc_free_lk` object, it does not allocate memory the members that are pointers, you need to allocate memory for them as well.

So `lk_header->buf_header` is pointing to nowhere, you cannot dereference it, it's undefined behaviour.
What you are seeing is a classic case of undefined behaviour.

Like I said, you have to initialize the member of the struct before you can access them.
You could use `calloc` instead of `malloc` because `calloc` sets the allocated
memory to 0, this helps when initializing pointers in structs.

```
stc_free_lk *link = calloc(1, sizeof *link);
if(link == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Not enough memory\n");
    return 1;
}

link->header = calloc(1, sizeof *link->header);
if(link->header == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Not enough memory\n");
    free(link);
    return 1;
}

init(link->lk_header, (unsigned)0, (unsigned)0);
...
```

Then in `init` you should also allocate memory for `lk_header->buf_header` and
`lk_header->data_area` and so on.

I suggest that you write a function that allocates all the memory for all the
pointers so that you don't have to allocate memory at different places. That
makes the code hard to follow and hard to find bugs. Also I'd write a `destroy`
function that `free`s all allocated memory, again all in one place.

Comment: ACK, I am trying

Comment: What if I still use malloc, but point what just allocated to NULL?

Comment: @W.Cameron sorry, I don't understand your question.